# Nested Arm Template with with multiple scopes

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Can anyone assist me with the issue I am having when I am trying to deploy multiple resources via Arm templates?
Since I have resources which are scoped on different levels, I am using nested Arm template deployment. I am trying to create new resource group which is scoped on subscription level and two resources, namely: Log Analytics workspace and Azure Sentinel which are scoped on resource group level. But when I run Powershell command New-AzSubscriptionDeployment I am getting an error, which is stated below:

*New-AzDeployment: 3:20:48 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/duo' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.
New-AzDeployment: The deployment validation failed*

My template is included below. I would really appreciate anyone’s help.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "resourceGroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of resource group."
            }
        },
        "resourceGroupLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of resource group."
            }
        },
        "workspaceNamePrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Prefix used for naming Log Analytics workspace."
            }   
        
        },
        "azureSentinelSolutionNamePrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Prefix used for naming Sentinel Solution."
            }
        }        
    },
    "variables": {
        "workspaceName": "[concat(parameters('workspaceNamePrefix'), uniqueString(subscription().id, parameters('resourceGroupName')))]",
        "azureSentinelSolutionName": "[concat(parameters('azureSentinelSolutionNamePrefix'), variables('workspaceName'))]",
        
        "product": "OMSGallery/SecurityInsights",
        "publisher": "Microsoft"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "location": "[parameters('resourceGroupLocation')]",
            "name": "[parameters('resourceGroupName')]",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "NestedTemplate",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourceGroupName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
                    "scope": "outer"
                },
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {  
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                    },
                    "Variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('workspaceName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('resourceGroupLocation')]",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "pergb2018"
                                },   
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]"
                            ]    
                        
                        },
                        {
                    
                            "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
                            "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
                            "name": "[variables('azureSentinelSolutionName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('resourceGroupLocation')]",
                            "plan": {                                                                                                                                
                                "name": "[variables('azureSentinelSolutionName')]",
                                "promotionCode": "",
                                "product": "[variables('product')]",
                                "publisher": "[variables('publisher')]"
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', variables('workspaceName'))]",
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "workspaceResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', variables('workspaceName'))]"
                            }
                                                    
                        }    
                    ],     
                    "outputs": {}
                }
            }
        }   
    ],   
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: can you try to remove all the `dependsOn` statements? Don't think those are needed here

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice and removed all the dependsOn statements with the partially successful deployment. The deployment of resource group and Log Analytics workspace succeeded, with Sentinel deployment failing. Do you have any advice on the failing part of this deployment, perhaps? Appreciate your input.

Comment: well, with which error message did it fail?

Comment: ah, you probably need to keep the dependsOn for the LA-workspace on Sentinel resource. Just remove the dependsOn for the resource group

Comment: so, I reinstated the dependsOn statement for the LA-workspace on Sentinel resource as you suggested but still the deployment of Sentinel failed with the error message: bad request.

Comment: There should be more error message details

Comment: Please see below for details:{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": "Bad request. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20210121T214052Z', subscription id ' ', tracking id 'fae82b2f-a014-4a54-b64f-c792f8743f0a', request correlation id '0e4382da-458e-402c-91fa-ec5ce278dd19'."
    }
  ]
}